# Changing data source of pivot tables with VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I'm looking for a code that can change the data source of my pivot tables from one sheet with a different data source.
The data source sheet is identical just with different data.

I have a code that i've taken from the internet, but instead of changing the data source of my active sheet, it changes the data source on all my sheets.

Sadly i don't know much about VBA coding to know how to change the code to affect only my active sheet and i was hoping someone could help me.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeDataSourceForAllPivotTables()

    Dim wb                  As Workbook
    Dim ws                  As Worksheet
    Dim pt                  As PivotTable
    Dim rSourceData         As Range

    If ActiveWorkbook Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Set rSourceData = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'change the name of the worksheet accordingly

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            pt.ChangePivotCache wb.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, rSourceData.Address(, , , True))
            pt.RefreshTable
        Next pt
    Next ws

ExitTheSub:
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set pt = Nothing
    Set rSourceData = Nothing

    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ":  " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    Resume ExitTheSub

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This code will help you to change Source Data for all Pivot Table in particular Sheet.**

```
Sub ChangePivotSourceData()

Dim pt As PivotTable

For Each pt In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables
         pt.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
            (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="MyData")
Next pt

End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- `Copy` & `Paste` this Code as `Standard 
  Module`.
- `Sheet` and `Source Data` names are editable.
- In this code **MyData** is a **Named Range**, 
  that you need to create  before you **RUN** 
  this Code every time you want to change *Source 
  Data for Pivot Table*.

Comment: Thank you very much! The code that you gave me works.

Comment: Glad to help you @PopClaudiu ,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

I would like to split a document by destination (for example) and create automatically various specific files (for each destination) with the relevant pivot chart. How to do to update the data source of the new pivot charts each time (Spain, Italy, France...) ? As they keep the original data source with all destinations (Europe). Thanks

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim MyData As Excel.ListObject
   
    Set MyData = Application.Range(Europe).ListObject
   
For Each pt In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Chart - City").PivotTables
         pt.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
            (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="MyData")
Next pt
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1159926)